Hola! Quiero poder hacer alertas a correos por fecha de vencimiento proxima
mi problema es que quiero poder enviar a correos electrónicos una alerta días antes de que venza algún contrato o alguna boleta de pago que tengan que realizar los administradores de mi empresa, tengo algunas ideas como realizarlo con Nodemailer (no recuerdo si se llamaba así) pero quisiera saber que otros modelos me pueden ayudar o alguna plataforma (sin pago) exista, muchas gracias, los leo!

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

La pregunta es muy genérica pero voy a intentar darte un ejemplo a ver si me acerco a lo que necesitas.
Usando Nodemailer
No tengo contexto de tus variables pero con esto mandas un mail automatico el dia 5 de cada mes
const cron = require('node-cron');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Configuración del transporte de nodemailer (SMTP)
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.example.com', // Cambiar a tu servidor de correo saliente
  port: 587, // Puerto SMTP
  secure: false, // true para 465, false para otros puertos
  auth: {
    user: 'tu_correo@example.com', // Cambiar a tu dirección de correo electrónico
    pass: 'tu_contraseña' // Cambiar a tu contraseña de correo electrónico
  }
});

// Función para enviar correo electrónico
const enviarCorreo = () => {
  // Definir opciones del correo electrónico
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'tu_correo@example.com',
    to: 'destinatario@example.com',electrónico
    subject: 'Asunto del correo electrónico', 
    text: 'Cuerpo del correo electrónico' 
  };

  // Enviar correo electrónico
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error al enviar el correo electrónico:', error);
    } else {
      console.log('Correo electrónico enviado:', info.response);
    }
  });
};

// Programar el envío de correo electrónico para el día 5 de cada mes a las 00:00
cron.schedule('0 0 5 * *', () => {
  console.log('Enviando correo electrónico...');
  enviarCorreo();
});

Recorda que tenes que instalar cron y nodemon.
usando:

npm i node-cron
npm i nodemon


Le podes pasar como variable la fecha en que vence cada boleta para que se envié el mail en ese momento.
